# Check whether Logged In when Button is clicked in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

Is there a quick way to label all buttons such that when clicked, the user will be displayed the login/signup page if he is not logged in. If he is logged in, the click event will propagate to the button.

This button does not result in a URL change.

I can only think of adding a `click .checkIfLoggedin` event listener to a template, and repeat the same code for each template. Is there a way that is less redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching the logic on the button, common practice is to put that logic in the destination. For example, the button goes to `membersOnly`, which forwards to the login page if the user is not logged in.

If the button is for an action that doesn't change the url (eg upvote), then you'll already have an event listener on it, so you can just call your check function at the top of the callback. All the buttons can call a single function.

If you have multiple buttons that do the same thing (eg lots of different places to upvote) then you'll end up having event listener callbacks that are all identical. If this is the case, you can treat that button like a component, give it its own template & event map, & then call it from the parent template (along with any necessary context). This obviates the need for cut and paste event listeners on varying parent templates.